# Usage rights of Ubuntu Font License

Tags: fonts, font-licensing

I want to use the Ubuntu Font Family in my designs. They are licensed with the UFL, which is confusing to me. Can I use fonts licensed with the UFL for making “things” (images, videos, documents etc.) – even for commercial usage –, and license them with other licenses (or keep the copyright)?

I understood that if I attach the font to my “thing”, the font will still be licensed under the UFL. And if someone extracts the font from my “thing”, the font will still be under the UFL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use fonts licensed with the UFL for making “things” (images, videos, documents etc.) – even for commercial usage –, and license them with other licenses (or keep the copyright)?

Yes you can. The UFL is pretty much the same as the OFL in these respects. From the [Ubuntu Font License](http://font.ubuntu.com/ufl/) (boldface mine):

> #### PREAMBLE
>
> This licence allows the licensed fonts to be used, studied, modified and redistributed freely. The fonts, including any derivative works, can be bundled, embedded, and redistributed provided the terms of this licence are met. The fonts and derivatives, however, cannot be released under any other licence. **The requirement for fonts to remain under this licence does not require any document created using the fonts or their derivatives to be published under this licence,** as long as the primary purpose of the document is not to be a vehicle for the distribution of the fonts.
>
> […]
>
> #### PERMISSION & CONDITIONS
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of the Font Software, to propagate the Font Software, subject to the below conditions:
>
> […]
>
> 2. e. The Font Software, modified or unmodified, in part or in whole, must be distributed entirely under this licence, and must not be distributed under any other licence. **The requirement for fonts to remain under this licence does not affect any document created using the Font Software**, except any version of the Font Software extracted from a document created using the Font Software may only be distributed under this licence.